# Why it is giving me 'this.state.UserData.map' is not a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I am getting an error in my code 'this.state.UserData.map' is not a function . i want get list from the database using fetch. i think i am forgetting something.
please help me remove this error. thanks in advance.
Here is my complete code to show list...

`````````
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
export default class FetchedData extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={ UserData:[] };
    this.headers=[
      {key:1,label:'Name'},
      {key:2,label:'Department'},
      {key:3,label:'Marks'},
    ];
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch("https://www.veomit.com/test/zend/api/fetch.php")
    .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
    .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    UserData:result
                })
        .catch(error => {
        console.log(
          "An error occurred while trying to fetch data from Foursquare: " +error
        );
      });
    });
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <table className="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              {
                        this.headers.map(function(h) {
                            return (
                                <th key = {h.key}>{h.label}</th>
                            );
                        })
                        }
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
              {
                        this.state.UserData.map(function(item){             
                        return (
                                <tr>
                                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                                  <td>{item.department}</td>
                                  <td>{item.marks}</td>
                                </tr>
                            );
                        })
                    }
          </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
````````
`````````

Comment: Inside the `.then(result => {...})`, do `console.log(result)`. What is it?

Comment: It means that `this.state.UserData` is not an array. Looking at the [URL](https://www.veomit.com/test/zend/api/fetch.php), it's an Object.

Comment: can you just show what `console.log(result)` is ? Probable reason is Your result is not `Array`,

Comment: yes you are right its is not an array.. i am getting object in the console.

Comment: your code giving me 'Cannot read property 'name' of null' error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your code I hope it's working for you.

Thanks

`````````
 import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    export default class FetchedData extends React.Component{
      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={ UserData:[] };
        this.headers=[
          {key:1,label:'Name'},
          {key:2,label:'Department'},
          {key:3,label:'Marks'},
        ];
      }

       componentWillMount() {
            fetch("https://www.veomit.com/test/zend/api/fetch.php")
            .then(response => {
                 return response.json();
            })
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    UserData: result
                });
             })
             .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(
                    "An error occurred while trying to fetch data from Foursquare: " +
                          error
                    );
            });
        }
      render(){
        return(
          <div>
          <table className="table table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  {
                            this.headers.map(function(h) {
                                return (
                                    <th key = {h.key}>{h.label}</th>
                                );
                            })
                            }
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                  { this.state.UserData.length > 0 ?
                         this.state.UserData.map((item,index) => (
                             <tr key={index}>
                                      <td>{item.name}</td>
                                      <td>{item.department}</td>
                                      <td>{item.marks}</td>
                                    </tr>
                          ))
                          ) : (
                               <tr>
                                  <td colspan="3">No record found.</td>
                                </tr>
                              )}
                  </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    ````````
`````````

Comment: he gave this.state.UserData.length > 0 ?

Comment: @JackBashford Please check your .map function. and also you need to check your data length.

Comment: But it's an object, not an array - see my answer. Objects don't have `length`.

Comment: In this statement .then(result => { this.setState({ UserData:result }) your result should return a array of objects, because you declared UserData as a array. If this.state.UserData is not an array then how can you map that.

Comment: @SanatGupta can u please check  and edit this
                     this.state.UserData.map((item,index) => (
                         <tr>
                                  <td>{item.name}</td>
                                  <td>{item.department}</td>
                                  <td>{item.marks}</td>
                                </tr>
                      )):
                       (
                           <tr>
                              <td>No record found.</td>
                            </tr>
                          )}

Comment: @Techiepop code updated please check. what you want.?
You are getting any error please let me know.

Comment: @SanatGupta https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ehwxdk please check this for issue near :

Comment: your code giving me 'Cannot read property 'name' of null' error.

Comment: Please try again actually error on inside componentWillMount() function now again update code there please check.

Answer (score 0):

The data is an object - you need to convert it to an array with `Object.values`:

```
UserData: Object.values(result)
```

Comment: now it is giving me 'Cannot read property 'name' of null error'

Answer (score 0):

response is not array. You need convert response server to array of object to use map

response must like this. You can tell backend services to change like this or you convert like this to your state

```
[{name: 'John Doe', department: 'CEO', marks: 'title' } , {....} ]
```